Jenkins devenv build not finishing because next command starts
I've been trying to setup a Jenkins build machine that uses Visual Studio 2010 building tool to build a C++ app. The build stops a minute after it started and Jenkins goes ahead with the next command. I tried to create a .bat file using the same commands as Jenkins but with no results, the build succeds and it does what i want it to.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "%WORKSPACE%\someproject.sln" /rebuild "Release"
In the event viewer i found the following error:
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, System.String, System.String, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions, Boolean)
   at Nokia.QtProjectLib.Messages.DisplayErrorMessage(System.String)
   at Qt4VSAddin.AddInEventHandler.ListenForRequests()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

The software versions are the following:

Jenkins: 2.375.2
Windows: 10 Pro x64
Java JDK: 17.0.5+9-LTS-191

I was expecting the build to succeed as building the project manually with VS2010 work.

Check if starting the build form cmd prompts you to install some features

Yes, thank you, it prompted me to install the Net 3.5 Framework, I tried installing it and it worked!

Check if starting the build from cmd prompts you to install some features, i think that block Jenkins from finishing the build
